# Getting Vector3.Dot to work based on player direction and angle?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity3D and I'm trying to determine the direction that the player is moving **only** when they are on an angled surface. Currently the code below works as it should on angled surfaces but when I stand on a flat surface and press W or A, the message "Moving uphill" activates, and when I press D or S, the message "Moving downhill" activates. When I am on a flat surface that should not happen but I'm not sure where the issue is.

```
// Update()
if (controller.isGrounded && Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out RaycastHit hit, 2f))
{

    Vector3 move = new Vector3(move.x, 0, move.y).normalized;
    float surfaceDot = Vector3.Dot(move, hit.normal);

    if (surfaceDot == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("On a flat surface");
    }
    else if (surfaceDot < 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Moving uphill");
        // Reduce player speed
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Moving downhill");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried actually printing out the value of the dot product? If your hit normal is even slightly non-zero you will get this behaviour due to your surface either not being truly flat or, due to floating point error resulting in a very small number. If your surfaceDot is almost but not quite zero I would consider building in some padding in the if statement conditions.

Comment: Yeah when I use `Debug.Log(surfaceDot)` I get really weird values. I get anything from -8f to 8.5f on flat surfaces when using WASD keys and my plane object (ground) has a default position of (0,0,0). When I test this on my different slopes, the value is normal and sits between -1f and 1f.

Comment: My other theory is that your move vector does not point truly upwards at 90 degrees. Is there a reason you are calculating a vector for this when Vector3.Up would suffice? I'm also not sure where you are getting the move.x and move.y porperties from, that you are passing into your constructor for the move vector.

Comment: So I'm just using Brackey's first person movement script to test this out, at the top of my `Update` I have `Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z` and so I just use those as both `move.x`and `move.z` for my code in the post. All the code I have is in the same `Update` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Vector3.Angle to calculate if it's an uphill or downhill.

```cs
// that angle returned by surfaceAngle for perfectly flat surface.
float flatAngle = 0f;

if (controller.isGrounded && Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out RaycastHit hit, 2f))
{
    float surfaceAngle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, hit.normal);

    // only activate if inclination is above 35°
    if (surfaceAngle - flatAngle < 35f)
    {
        Debug.Log("On a flat surface");
    }
    else if (surfaceAngle < 90f)
    {
        Debug.Log("Moving uphill");
        // Reduce player speed
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Moving downhill");
    }
}
```

If the surface can tilt in all directions, then this might be more difficult.

Comment: Sorry I should have included that I'm using Unity3D. I have tested out this code just now and it seems that it is inverted. When I move uphill, the game says that I'm moving downhill and vice versa. Would I need to alter the value of the else if statement?

Comment: I just amended the code, yes if it's the wrong way around just flip the comparison in the else if statement.

Comment: you can also put an eror margin in your first if `(surfaceAngle >85 && surfaceAngle <95)` or similar if your surface is not perfectly flat.

Comment: Thanks a lot I believe this works so far. I kept the `surfaceangle == 0` rather than `== 90` but I will keep testing for the next few minutes and hopefully everything is all good. Edit: I think everything works

Comment: Yeah ,that would make more sense. You just need to figure out the angle for perfectly flat surfaces and then check if the angle is more than 35° different to activate the slope.
`surfaceAngle - flatAngle < 35f`

Comment: Yeah I created a second angle, and inside the else if statement I create an if statement saying (if angle > 35f) -> slow down movement speed. Also, I'm just curious what you mean by if the surface is not flat, would that error margin include a sphere?

Comment: No,I essentially meant the same thing you just implemented yourself. Thet it doesn't activate on any slightest tilt of the surface due to some error.

Comment: Oh I understand, thanks a lot